# Possiblity of Using Transistor as Resistor

Tags: transistors, mosfet, resistors, ac, integrated-circuit

[image]I would like to know it if is posible to use NMOS transistor to act as a resistor with a sinusoidal power supply ?

The circuit I have is very simple; it consists of a 20Vpp-sinusoidal source connected to a resistor (100 M to 700 M Ohm) then to ground. However, I want to replace the resistor with an NMOS transistor such that the circuit behaves in a similar manner.

So, would it be possible to do that without a DC source? Given that I can design my own NMOS transistor with any parameters values I need, such as Vth, mobility, W/L,...etc

I know for a fact that if the transistor is to act as a resistor it must be in the triode region where VGS > Vth & VDS < VGS - Vth, but I am not sure if it is going to work with no DC biasing source.

Comment: To keep it in the triode region at the exact point where the Rds is the value you want, you need some feedback. The easiest is to use an opamp to drive the fet gate, then. But your requirement is strange. You should provide more information about the ultimate goal you're trying to achieve.

Comment: MY ultimate goal is not to use resistor in the circuit.

Comment: But... why? Are you trying to make a resistor switchable? A resistor that can change its value? You can't just decide to replace a resistor by a mosfet without a real *goal* behind, can you? Tell us more about that, because we won't be able to make relevant, good-quality answers otherwise.

Comment: Linear regulators typically use a transistor as a (variable) resistor; see, for example, [Understanding LDO Regulators](http://focus.ti.com/download/trng/docs/seminar/Topic%209%20-%20Understanding%20LDO%20dropout.pdf) (PDF). But what *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: Sounds like you're actually designing an IC. If that's true, you _must_ inform us about this quite vital information.

Comment: I do not want to use resistors because they are too bulky for my application. And yes, I am designing an IC circuit for a research purpose, and I've reached to that situation where I have only AC feeding transistors which are meant to be resistors.

Comment: _"I do not want to use resistors because they are too bulky for my application."_ - And what makes you think a transistor will be any less bulky? The power dissipated will be the same...

Comment: If your not making an active resistor then just use a resistor.

Comment: Your making a 'parasitic' resistor? It's still a resistor. Is this turning into an apple and oranges debate? If so VTC.

Comment: @marcelm: Resistors are much much larger than transistors in integrated circuits.  I mean, orders of magnitude larger, especially to get any substantial resistance value.  It is very common practice (I would say standard practice) to use FET's as an active resistor.  Because they are a lot smaller.  But obviously this adds more complexity to the design because you need to make sure the resistance stays constant enough over its operating range by proper biasing on the FET's.

Comment: @Fahad I'm downvoting because it is a shame you still didn't update your question to indicate you're designing an IC. This is obviously a crucial information. Giving it in the comments is not enough. If you update your question appropriately, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @dim: dude it's been tagged IC the whole time.

Comment: @jbord39 An IC tag? We're supposed to see that and guess it means you're *designing* an IC? Seriously, just add a sentence to your question.

Comment: @dim: It's not my question.  but, it was clear to me

Comment: @jbord39 Yeah, I first thought answer was from OP. Sorry. But it doesn't change what I think. I even made a [post on meta](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5885/providing-question-context-in-tags) about that because I was really stunned by this implicit meaning of this tag.

Comment: @dim: I'm just curious, what did you think the integrated circuit tag means?

Comment: @jbord39 As I explained in the meta post, I didn't looked at the tags (I always miss this), so I didn't think anything. But anyway, check the questions having this "integrated-circuit" tag, you'll see it's about anything. And ASIC design is certainly a very small proportion of this. So I don't know what this tag means. I know what is an IC, but I don't think I can make assumptions on the *usage* of this tag.

Answer (score 3):

This technique of using FET's as resistors is commonly done in ICs because the resistors have to be huge to get any substantial resistance values.  Keep in mind that the simulations I have below are ideal.  In an IC, especially smaller technologies, you will have significant channel length modulation.  This means that in saturation and increase in Vds increases the current.  This would actually soften the quadratic behavior of the square law-connected NMOS in your schematic.

However, it works best if you can bias the FET's with DC values.  I would also like to point out that the FET's in IC are way different than the IRF530's which another user simulated.  Those are power FET's and completely different beasts from the FET's on an IC.

I have attached a simulation showing the setup you have now.  The FET's are just ideal models, you would need to include the actual models into your sim.  I plotted V-I (straight line implies linear resistance) on the right side, you can see it's not perfectly linear.  This is because hooked up like that the FET acts as a square law device.  VGS = VDS, the FET is in saturation, and:

$$
I_d = A*(V_{gs}-V_t)^2
$$

If you take the differential resistance as dV/dI:

$$
dI/dV = R_d = \frac{1}{2A(V_{gs}-V_t)}
$$

So, quite non-linear.

[image: square law rdiff]

If instead you bias with a constant VGS, you can keep the FET in the "ohmic" or linear region.  I didn't spend much time but you can see the idea from the simulations below.

[image: some sims]

If you bias with a DC source it looks a lot better.  You will need to get the actual FET models for the fab you are using, and include them in your simulations.  Check the V-I over your operating range and attempt to make it as linear as possible.

If you can, combine a PMOS / NMOS w/ DC bias for a much more linear V-I curve, which means a near-constant R value.  Since you are designing an IC you have control over the relative sizing of the NMOS/PMOS; play with this knob to help compensate better:
[image: very linear resistance]

As I was thinking about it, if you can use a diode there is no reason you can't just produce a DC-ish voltage to bias the FET.  For the cap, use another MOSFET gate with it's source/drain tied to ground (sometimes also ties S/D/G, the ground connection is through the substrate) check your design rules for which is preferred in your technology).

So finally below, is a very linear resistor biased with a generated DC voltage.

[image: wgenerateddcbias]

Just for reference, this is what the VI curve looks like for the circuit the OP posted.  Each device is acting as a square law device and the whole thing doesn't start conducting until 3*VGS + Vdiode, which is very exaggerated in a power FET, since their threshold voltages are ~7 times that of IC FET's.

[image: original circuit from OP]

Answer (score 0):

That won't work because if you apply an AC sinusoid to the gate, and the transistor isn't biased in some way, then when the AC signal goes more negative than Vth, the transistor will be cut off and will remain cut off for the entire negative half-cycle, so the resistance of the transistor will only change when the gate is more positive than Vth.

**EDIT:**

It appears that there's more to this than meets the eye.

Take a look at the red trace, below, and then run the attached LTspice circuit list to zoom in around zero G\$\Omega\$.

[image]

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 192 0 112 0
WIRE 336 0 256 0
WIRE 416 0 336 0
WIRE 416 48 416 0
WIRE 336 128 336 0
WIRE 368 128 336 128
WIRE 416 176 416 144
WIRE 416 176 336 176
WIRE 416 208 416 176
WIRE 336 288 336 176
WIRE 368 288 336 288
WIRE 416 336 416 304
WIRE 416 336 336 336
WIRE 416 368 416 336
WIRE 112 384 112 0
WIRE 336 448 336 336
WIRE 368 448 336 448
WIRE 112 512 112 464
WIRE 416 512 416 464
WIRE 416 512 112 512
WIRE 112 592 112 512
FLAG 112 592 0
SYMBOL nmos 368 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value IRF530
SYMBOL nmos 368 48 R0
SYMATTR InstName M2
SYMATTR Value IRF530
SYMBOL nmos 368 368 R0
SYMATTR InstName M3
SYMATTR Value IRF530
SYMBOL diode 192 16 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value 1N4148
SYMBOL voltage 112 368 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 20 1000)
TEXT 128 544 Left 2 !.tran 5m uic
```

Comment: I am actually applying the AC to the drain of the transistor which is also connected to gate. So I have VDS= VGS and the only way to make that transistor operates in triode region is to make Vth below 0, which I achieved already. But the question is, is it possible to do such a thing ? Do I need a DC supply to force the transistor act as a resistor in triode region ?

Comment: Moreover, I can eliminate the negative cycle of the sinusoidal by adding a diode at the source. Just to make sure VGS does not go below Vth. So that's not a problem here.

Comment: @Fahad:  I apologize for not having brought this up earlier, but you could allay a great deal of confusion (for me, at least)  if you'd edit your question by adding a schematic describing what you have in mind. As it stands now, you seem to be saying that you want the transistor's drain-to-source resistance to change only on the positive half-cycles of the input signal's excursion, while earlier it seemed you wanted the \$ R_{DS}\$ to change over the entire cycle. Can you clear up what it is you want to do, please?

Comment: I have attached the schematic of the circuit I am talking about.

Comment: Can anyone expect the behavior of this circuit ? Will there be a current flowing through the transistors ? Giving that the amplitude of the sine wave is 15 V and all the transistors are identical and have Vth = -1 V

Comment: @EM Fields:You are using power MOSFET's in your simulation.  They are just about as off-spec as you can get to the FET's in an IC, so the problems seen in your sim probably won't apply.

Comment: @jbord39: Regardless of all that hoopla about the FETs available in ICs, the circuit I posted and simulated is identical to the OP's so, if you have a problem with that, I suggest you find fault with the OP.

Comment: @EM Fields: That is true.  I think he just used the default FET's.  I guess my point is that the phenomenon you are observing is more than likely an artifact of the power FET's.  They have much different characteristics, including a very large gate cap.  There is usually a diode between source and drain to prevent reverse current.

Comment: @jbord39: So post a circuit which refutes what you disagree with.

Comment: @EM Fields: Ok, I attached the original circuit the OP linked replaced with ideal components instead of power FET's.

Comment: @jbord39: As I understand the OP's question, he's asking for a way to generate a fixed drain-to-source resistance from a garden-variety MOSFET array using no DC biasing and nothing more than a clever way to connect the AC source to the array. None of your examples seem to fulfill that requirement.

Comment: @EM Fields: And I gave him the results of a few different methods.  And he said he can use a diode, and NMOS.  So creating a DC-enough bias is simple enough.  Regardless I explained the resistance if he cannot do that and has to use them as square law devices, as he showed.  And also, these are garden variety FET's that I used.  They are in fact the default models.  Anyway I provided 4 solutions and included the IV curves, which shows the resistance for each one.  What more do you want?

Comment: @jbord39: By describing ideal IC NMOS and ideal discretes you seem to be skirting the issue which - as the OP clearly stated - is whether it's possible for a transistor array, configured as he showed, to exhibit the properties of a fixed resistance of a particular value with only an AC signal into the array.

Comment: No, I clearly answered the question.  You provided some essentially random simulation which doesn't correspond to the situation.  He clearly says that this is for an IC, so why use power mosfets to draw conclusions??? And I showed the behaviour through a sim. I also spoke about how real FET's on an IC would have more channel length modulation, softening the effect of the square law behaviour.  Yes, he can use it as a resistor if he is okay with a pretty nonconstant resistance (and keeps Vin positive to forward bias).  Or, if he wants he can improve that using other modifications I suggested.

Comment: @jbord39: You answered a multitude of questions, most of which **you** posed, but not the one the OP posed, which  was whether it's possible for a transistor array, configured as he showed, to exhibit the properties of a fixed resistance of a particular value with only an AC signal into the array.  Your last comment, from which I excerpted: "Yes, he can use it as a resistor if he is okay with a pretty nonconstant resistance." seems to put us in agreement,  as can be seen from the resistance VS voltage plot of my sim.